# How to pass two model's pk in url Django? - <int:pk> | id

Tags: django, python-3.x, url

When I wrote code as below:

```
path('project/<int:pk>/user/<int:pk>/project-detail', app.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='project_user_detail'),
```

I got the error of

```
raise source.error(err.msg, len(name) + 1) from None
sre_constants.error: redefinition of group name 'pk' as group 2; was group 1 at position 35
```

I would like to know how to pass 2 pk/id from different models, thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just give them unique names. You'd need to anyway, so that they can be resolved into a dict:

```
>>> def view():
...     pass
... 
>>> p = path('project/<int:project_id>/user/<int:user_id>/project-detail', view)
>>> p.resolve('project/123/user/456/project-detail').kwargs
{'project_id': 123, 'user_id': 456}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for swift reply, do you know how to define the template of `project_user_list.html` ? I wrote as below: `<a target="_blank" href="{% url 'app:project_user_detail' project.pk user.pk %}"` but it says `Generic detail view ProjectDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.`

Comment: I recommend you ask a new question, being sure to include all the necessary details to reproduce the issue.